# anyone came across this "/usr/local/bin/footloose: line 1: Not: command not found" when running footloose

Tags: linux, containers, virtual-machine

Very simple installation:

Linux

```
curl -Lo footloose https://github.com/weaveworks/footloose/releases/download/0.6.4/footloose-0.6.4-linux-x86_64
chmod +x footloose
sudo mv footloose /usr/local/bin/
```

I tried both Cetos 7.6 and ubuntu 16, and got the same result

Comment: url you are trying to download is 404, resulting file that is downloaded only contains a string "Not Found". That is hardly an executable nor a working shell script.

Comment: For version 0.6.3 there are binaries available, but for 0.6.4. there are only source code archives. Check https://github.com/weaveworks/footloose/releases/

Comment: Thanks!, I should have checked that :\